# Change Logging Level for HttpServletBean logger

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

The logger I am referring to is being called from a method in the `DispatcherServlet`:

```
protected ModelAndView processHandlerException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

    // Check registered HandlerExceptionResolvers...
    ModelAndView exMv = null;
    for (HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver : this.handlerExceptionResolvers) {
        exMv = handlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(request, response, handler, ex);
        if (exMv != null) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (exMv != null) {
        if (exMv.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        // We might still need view name translation for a plain error model...
        if (!exMv.hasView()) {
            exMv.setViewName(getDefaultViewName(request));
        }
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: " + exMv, ex);
        }
        WebUtils.exposeErrorRequestAttributes(request, ex, getServletName());
        return exMv;
    }

    throw ex;
  }
```

I think by default it is set to 'debug'. How can I change it to 'Error' so that it won't print out 'WARN' stack traces?

Thanks

Comment: What is your logger? Log4J or SLF4J or anything else? It depends on your logger setting.

Comment: By setting the log level for the `DispatcherServlet` to error.